# Схема БД для хранения результатов тестирования по учебным предметам

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, проектирование

До сегодняшнего для хранил результаты тестирования (диагностических работ) в одной таблице :). Хотя всегда понимал, что это не нормально. Понятное дело, что иногда приходится отходить от каких-то форм нормализации, но не настолько.

И теперь, после декомпозици, вот такую схему теперь предлагаю я сам себе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И люди добрые, прошу сделать свои замечания.

У меня у самого есть замечание, но не могу ничего иного предложить:

Мне не нравится, что получается так много составных ключей. Наверное как-то правильно было бы использовать тип `uniqueindetifier`? В таблице `WorkParticips` я не могу использовать `uniqueindetifier`, т.к. этот ИД мне часто надо передавать самим участникам. Стоит ли в таблицах `SubjectParticips` и `SubjectResults` поманипулировать с `uniqueindetifier`? Или в предложенной схеме есть проблемы по серьезнее?

Comment: Сижу, смотрю на схему... вот  КАК надо себе представлять процесс тестирования во времени и пространстве, чтобы нарисовать ему такую схему?

Comment: @Akina, извини, но не совсем понял мысль. Я очень хорошо нарисовал или очень плохо? :)

Comment: С моей точки зрения схема вообще никак не соотносится с процессом. Наверное, это следует квалифицировать как "плохо". Попробуйте забыть, что у Вас что-то есть (таблица с данными, старый анализ и пр.), и начать всё с самого начала, с чистого листа. Имхо Вам же будет проще.

Comment: _Попробуйте забыть, что у Вас что-то есть_ @Akina так я как раз это и делаю. Дело в том, что база признаны хранить только СТАТИСТИЧЕСКУЮ информацию. Никаких данных о самой процедуре нет в БД.

Comment: Но это вовсе не означает, что сущность Работа становится атрибутом сущности Участник.

Comment: @Akina, но это ведь СОСТАВНОЙ ключ. Или как по твоему в реляционной модели указать участие участника в некой работе?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50276/discussion-between-adamshakhabov-and-akina).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите на такой вариант, без составных ключей:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]